# Remove highlight on a selected button from a ToggleButtonBar

Tags: apache-flex, highlight, togglebuttonbar

Well, title explains all. I'm trying to get rid of the highlight that comes around of the selected button in a ToggleButtonBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually find how to resolve it, quiet simple actually! (Thanks to the KapInspect tool)

I just had to create a custom skin for the selectedDownSkin style

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact look you want your best bet is to jump in Flash, Fireworks, Photoshop, etc and tweak a button skin to your liking. The border is part of the skin. You can create a programmatic skin as well.

A quick fix is to set the highlight the same color as the button.

> ToggleButtonBar{
>   button-style-name: "myButton";
>   }
>
> Button.myButton{
>   theme-color: #999999;
>   }

Mind you...it is purely a quick fix and will tweak your button hover color as well so only use it as a small win.

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add I only use Programmatic Skin.
If I set theme-color to my button color doesn't really fix the problem as its border thickness is too large.

Take a look at this screenshot to see what I'm talking about :

http://img4.imageshack.us/i/toggle.jpg/

Comment: Oh that makes it different. :-) Glad you went ahead and did a skin for the selected down.